# RTK-query aims for the params when it should skip

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, rtk-query

RTK-query accepts `skip` option to skip the request when the option is true:

```
const {data} = useGetMyDataQuery(myParams, {skip: myCondition});
```

I expect the skip is being checked before it accesses `myParams` and skip running that code when it's supposed to be skipped.

For example in the following code, I expect the function not be run when `myCondition` is true.

```
const getMyParams = () => params; 
const {data} = useGetMyDataQuery(getMyParams(), {skip: myCondition});
```

In [this](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/redux-toolkit-rtk-query-forked-75hr93?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu14rtf700072e674ingm4o4%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu14rtf700032e673wc0jf2x%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu14rtf700042e67yfwp7sf2%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu14rtf700062e67q7eohd8g%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clu14rtf700032e673wc0jf2x%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu14rtf700032e673wc0jf2x%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu14s9ol00022e664xx1frso%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A3%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A49%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A3%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A49%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FPokemon.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu14s9ol00022e664xx1frso%2522%257D%252C%2522clu14rtf700062e67q7eohd8g%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu14rtf700052e67eqj92p19%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu14rtf700062e67q7eohd8g%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu14rtf700052e67eqj92p19%2522%257D%252C%2522clu14rtf700042e67yfwp7sf2%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu14rtf700042e67yfwp7sf2%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) example I'm getting the parameters from an object which is possibly undefined. I skip the call when the object is undefined, so I expect the parameter code only runs when the condition is met. But it's not the case and you can see it gives a null pointer error when you click on "Add empty" button.

Is it the normal behavior of RTK-query or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has nothing to do with RTK Query, that's how JavaScript works.

`useGetMyDataQuery` is a function, and arguments are evaluated before they are passed to the function. RTK Query has no knowledge if you write `myParams` or `getMyParams()` there - it only ever sees the final value.

You can use `skipToken` instead here:

```js
import {skipToken} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'
const {data} = useGetMyDataQuery(myCondition ? skipToken : getMyParams());
```